# How to evaluate this line integral (Python-Sympy)

Tags: python, sympy, numeric, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

The idea is to compute the line integral of the following vector field and curve:

[image]

[image]

This is the code I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from sympy import Curve, line_integrate
from sympy.abc import x, y, t
C = Curve([cos(t) + 1, sin(t) + 1, 1 - cos(t) - sin(t)], (t, 0, 2*np.pi))
line_integrate(y * exp(x) +  x**2 + exp(x) + z**2 * exp(z), C, [x, y, z])
```

But the ValueError: Function argument should be (x(t), y(t)) but got [cos(t) + 1, sin(t) + 1, -sin(t) - cos(t) + 1] comes up.

How can I compute this line integral then?

I think that maybe this line integral contains integrals that don't have exact solution. It is also fine if you provide a numerical approximation method.

Thanks

Comment: If you look at the [source code](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/geometry/curve.html) for the curve function, it only supports 2D parametric curves, which explains your valueError.

Comment: Oh I see, then how can I evaluate a line integral for a 3D curve? If Sympy cannot you can provide an alternative (with Python as language please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value error you receive does not come from your call to the `line_integrate` function; it comes because according to the [source code](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/geometry/curve.html) for the `Curve` class, only functions in 2D Euclidean space are supported. This integral can still be computed without using sympy according to [this research blog](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2018/11/16/Line-integrals-in-Python-with-autograd/) that I found by simply searching for a workable method on Google.

The code you need looks like this:

```
import autograd.numpy as np
from autograd import jacobian
from scipy.integrate import quad

def F(X):
    x, y, z = X
    return [y * np.exp(x), x**2 + np.exp(x), z**2 * np.exp(z)]

def C(t):
    return np.array([np.cos(t) + 1, np.sin(t) + 1, 1 - np.cos(t) - np.sin(t)])

dCdt = jacobian(C, 0)

def integrand(t):
    return F(C(t)) @ dCdt(t)

I, e = quad(integrand, 0, 2 * np.pi)
```

The variable `I` then stores the numerical solution to your question.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can compute the integral using line_integrate because we can reduce the 3d integral to a 2d one. I'm sorry to say I don't know python well enough to write the code, but here's the drill:
If we write

```
C(t) = x(t),y(t),z(t)
```

then the thing to notice is that

```
z(t) = 3 - x(t) - y(t)
```

and so

```
dz = -dx - dy
```

So, we can write

```
F.dr = Fx*dx + Fy*dy + Fz*dz
     = (Fx-Fz)*dx + (Fy-Fz)*dy
```

So we have reduced the problem to a 2d problem: we integrate

```
G = (Fx-Fz)*i + (Fx-Fz)*j
```

round

```
t -> x(t), y(t)
```

Note that in G we need to get rid of z by substituting

```
z = 3 - x - y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
def linea3(f,C):
 P = f[0].subs([(x,C[0]),(y,C[1]),(z,C[2])])
 Q = f[1].subs([(x,C[0]),(y,C[1]),(z,C[2])])
 R = f[2].subs([(x,C[0]),(y,C[1]),(z,C[2])])
 dx = diff(C[0],t)
 dy = diff(C[1],t)
 dz = diff(C[2],t)
 m = integrate(P*dx+Q*dy+R*dz,(t,C[3],C[4]))
 return m
```

Then use the example:

```
 f = [x**2*z**2,y**2*z**2,x*y*z]
 C = [2*cos(t),2*sin(t),4,0,2*sp.pi]
```